# How to query a period of time using MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
Fee
idFee | dateStart  | dateEnd
1     | 2015-01-03 | 2015-01-20
2     | 2015-01-21 | 2015-01-24
3     | 2015-01-27 | 2015-01-28
```

I would like to get the "Fees" depending on a period of time.

**CASE 1:**
For example if I query the following dates:

```
queryDateStart: 2015-01-04
queryDateEnd: 2015-01-23
```

I should get the "Fees" 1 and 2. This is the tricky case as it has to concatenate the Fees 1 and 2 in order to get the results.

**CASE 2:**
If I query:

```
queryDateStart: 2015-01-23
queryDateEnd: 2015-01-24
```

I should get the Fee 2

**CASE 3:**
And if I query:

```
queryDateStart: 2015-01-05
queryDateEnd: 2015-01-28
```

I should get no "Fees" as there's a hole between the 24th and 27th. This could be another ticky case, as it has to concatenate all the dates and search for holes.

Is there a way to query this table? or do you think I should recover all the Fees and the process the results in PHP or JS?

I am using the following type query right now:

```
SELECT * FROM Fee WHERE
DATE_FORMAT(dateStart, "%Y-%m-%d")<="queryDateStart"
AND DATE_FORMAT(dateEnd, "%Y-%m-%d")>="queryDateEnd"
```

But it only works for one period of time, it doesn't manage two or more periods of time.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: From what I can see, your date format is different from what mysql uses by default. What's your table structure, and what query do you use?

Comment: @Strawbery yes it just edited the post... FIA2008 nope... I can use a DATE_FORMAT and it's cool with that

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a `date` column type, there's a couple of different ways

```
SELECT idFee, dateStart, dateEnd
FROM Fee
WHERE dateStart >= '2015-04-01' 
AND dateEnd <= '2015-24-01'
```

or

```
SELECT idFee, dateStart, dateEnd
FROM Fee
WHERE dateStart BETWEEN '2015-04-01' AND '2015-24-01'
```

Comment: None of your solutions work for two consecutive periods of time (CASE 1)

Comment: @leanyomartinet struggling to understand what your logic is, has the query to select rows that have the start dater after the query start date __OR__ the end date before the query end date?

Comment: the idea is to query consecutive periods of time using a period of time. your first solutions works but just for the CASES 2 and 3 that I've described... the most difficult one to solve is the CASE 1

Comment: @leanyomartinet managed to get this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13fcbb/5 but not sure if this is the logic you are looking for, I still don't understand your third case.

Comment: the third case triggers NULL because there's a hole between the second and third Fee... there are 3 days where there's no Fee... anyways I have been checking and I think it's an impossible query... thanks for trying anyway !

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look here:
[Selecting records between two date range query](http://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/between-date.php)

> **Between two date ranges.**
>
> Now let us move to select a range of records
>   between two dates. Here is the sql for this SELECT * FROM `dt_tb`
>   WHERE dt BETWEEN '2005-01-01' AND '2005-12-31'

That should do the trick.

Comment: Not at all... here you are using just dt_tb... and in my table I have to handle periods of time... not just one date

Comment: dt_tb is just a table name, you can change that to whatever you want. The BETWEEN date1 AND date2 is the part of your 2 datetime periods. Just as the tablename, you can change date1 and date2 to every valid date you like.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "dt"... is just one date... and I want to query periods of time... querying dates is easy